# React setState sort method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different code which sorts an array of numbers in an increasing order.

```
[...arr].sort((a,b) => {
            return a- b;
          }

arr.sort((a,b) => {
            return a- b;
          }
```

Both will return a sorted array of numbers.

But when inserted into a setState method in a React application, first sort works while the second one doesn't.

For the second sort, I suspect it's got something to do with modifying the original array, which React cannot detect as a change and so will not re-render the change. Why doesn't React detect this as a change?

Comment: "*Why doesn't React detect this as a change?*" - because it's still the *same* array. `arr === arr.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either `[...arr]` or `arr`, if you assign the method into a variable in advance. To explain this more, assume that there's a checkbox, every time you check it the method gets executed. Please take a look into the below example:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
```

With the spread operator:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sArr = [3, 1, 6];
    
    // Assigned into y
    const y = [...sArr].sort((a, b) => {
      return a - b;
    });

    setArr(y);
    console.log(arr);
}, [checked]);
```

Without the spread operator:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sArr = [3, 1, 6];

    // Assigned into y
    const y = sArr.sort((a, b) => {
      return a - b;
    });

    setArr(y);
    console.log(arr);
}, [checked]);
```